# Facing issue org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis'

Tags: groovy, jmeter

We are facing below issue while running the thread -

> "org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' class
>
> org.bouncycastle.util.Encodable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

However, same .jmx file is working fine on another system.

Comment: Different (wrong) bouncycastle jar on the system that's failing?

Comment: I have no clue about this jar file as same jmx is running with the same settings on different system.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the difference is in Java version used on the two system.

Check that the groovy jar is compatible with the version of Java where it is not working

Comment: Both machines having the same version.

Comment: can you share jmeter.log for both machines? also list content of jmeter/lib and jmeter/lib/ext thanks